# System commands not executing in PHP

Tags: php, shell, command, exec, shell-exec

I have a php script where some system commands are running fine and others are not. The commands that are not running can be copy and pasted to the shell and be ran just fine.

System: OSX 10.9.2 (everything is updated).

I have tried many different commands like the following.

backticks, `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `system()`, `passthru()`

This command works fine.

```
exec("drush si -y --db-url=mysql://user:pass@localhost:3306/dbname");
```

But these commands do not run.

```
exec("drush sql-sync @remote.staging @dev.anme -y");
exec("git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:blablaname/name.git");
```

The commands that do not run can be copy and pasted into the shell and run great. I have made sure the script is being ran in the proper directory using the `getcwd()` function.

Comment: Why do you think those commands "are not run"? Any error message? You should implement error detection and handling anyway, so that you know what is going on. At least you should look at your http servers log file to read the error message, if those commands _really_ are not executed, which I doubt.

Comment: Btw: you sure your `PATH` is correct? Have a try using absolute path to those commands you try to execute.

Comment: what is the value of `disable_functions` in your php.ini?

Comment: Try putting the command in a variable and then executing it through that. That's how I run 'em and they work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you call php program having exec() from web browser,It executes as www user. So www user may not have privilege to connect/sync to remote host.That's why it works on localhost and failing on remote host.

So one solution is

1)save the command as bash script 
2)set uid bit(It can be root or user having sufficient privilege).
3)execute that bash script by exec so that it will run as previlged user.
4)You should ip restrict your program since setuid is dangerous.

[setuid](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html)